# using mclust's hc function for agglomorative clustering, how can we visualize the results? or plot a dendogram from the hc/hclass' output?

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

suppose I have data as mydata and G as the number of classification

```
hTree <- hc(mydata)
classification <- hclass(hTree, G)
```

How do I use this classification object to plot a dendogram?

Comment: Have you tried using just plot() ? what do you get?

Comment: sure, the output of hclass() is a matrix of #samples by G. So, using plot() will not give the dendogram.